# How to solve 3^x = 2187 by using Casio fx-85GT plus

Tags: calculator

I need to solve 3^x = 2187 by using Casio fx-85GT plus and I couldn't find anything in its manual.

I know how to do it manually and the answer is "x = 7". But how can I do it using the calculator. Please advise, many thanks!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMhPv.png)

Regards,

Comment: Take logs of both sides, any base you like.  That will give you $x\log 3 =\log {2187}$ and you can now just divide.

Comment: Thanks lulu, it worked!

Comment: An educated guess on $x$ would be $x=7$. Now try to verify that $3^7=2187$.  For that purpose type $$3 x^\square 7=$$ on your calc

Comment: @lulu Could you please convert your comment into an answer to remove this question from the "Unanswered" queue? Seems like you've answered this question pretty thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comments:

Taking $\log$ helps.  We see $$x\times \log 3 = \log 2187\implies x= \frac {\log 2187}{\log 3}$$

Here I intend the natural log, but any base would work.  Using any sort of calculator one then gets $x=7$.

Note:  it is easy to verify that $3^7=2187$ which confirms the result.